# Can anyone explain this error code I'm getting deploying MERN project through Render?

Tags: mern, render.com

Whenever I try to deploy the server/backend, I get this error code through Render:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/index.js'
```

I don't know what action to take.

Comment: Not sure what you think we can add - it's looking for a file `src/index.js` in your project files, and not finding it. Without a [mre] that's all we can say. Action to take would be: figure out why it's looking for that file (if you're not expecting it to) or where that file's gone (if you are).

Comment: i dont have a index.js in my src folder, its in my server folder. Im looking in the file still and i dont see what the issue can be.

Comment: `/opt/render/project/src` is where it puts your code, so it's looking for `index.js` in the root. If yours is in a subfolder, there's your problem. [This](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/tree/v2) deploys fine, maybe compare what you have with that.